# 境界条件を含めたランダムウォーク

Tags: python, python3, numpy, random

以下のステージ上(3次元)で乱数を生成させながら、ランダムウォークさせるときに、stageを条件文として以下のようにコードを書きましたが、うまく動くときと動かない時があります。自分としては完璧だと思ったのですが、なぜ計算されないのか頭を悩ませています。

```
stage=[[[1. 1. 1.]
      [1. 0. 1.]
      [1. 1. 1.]]

     [[1. 0. 1.]
      [0. 0. 0.]
      [1. 0. 1.]]

     [[1. 1. 1.]
      [1. 0. 1.]
      [1. 1. 1.]]]
```

メイン計算

```
import numpy as np
import random
import itertools
stage = np.array([[[1,1,1],
                    [1,0,1],
                    [1,1,1]],
                   [[1,0,1],
                    [0,0,0],
                    [1,0,1]],
                   [[1,1,1],
                    [1,0,1],
                    [1,1,1]]],dtype=np.uint8)
n = 3
itr = 5
step = [i for i in range(0,itr)]
r_list = [i for i in range(0,n)]
walk = np.zeros([n,n,n],dtype=np.uint8)
walk[0,0,0] = 1
#for k in range(0,1):
for t in step:
    if t == 0:
        pass
    else:
        number = random.randint(1,6)
        next_walk = np.zeros([n,n,n],dtype=np.uint8)
        print(t,number)
        for i in itertools.product(r_list,r_list,r_list):
            x = i[0]
            y = i[1]
            z = i[2]
        #Boundary condition
            x1 = (x-1 + n) % n
            x2 = (x+1) % n
            y1 = (y-1 + n) % n
            y2 = (y+1) % n
            z1 = (z-1 + n) % n
            z2 = (z+1) % n
            if stage[i]== 0:
                continue

            elif number == 1 and stage[x1,y,z]==1 and stage[x,y,z]==1:
                next_walk[x,y,z]= np.copy(walk[x1,y,z])#*(1/6))
            elif number==1 and stage[x1,y,z]==0 and stage[x,y,z]==1:
                next_walk[i]= walk[i]#(1/6)**t

            elif number == 2 and stage[x,y1,z]==1 and stage[x,y,z]==1:
                next_walk[x,y,z]= np.copy(walk[x,y1,z])#*(1/6))
            elif number==2 and stage[x,y1,z]==0 and stage[x,y,z]==1:
                next_walk[i]=walk[i]#(1/6)**t

            elif number == 3 and stage[x,y,z1]==1 and stage[x,y,z]==1:
                next_walk[x,y,z]= np.copy(walk[x,y,z1])#*(1/6))
            elif number==3 and stage[x,y,z1]==0 and stage[x,y,z]==1:
                next_walk[i]=walk[i]#(1/6)**t

            elif number == 4 and stage[x2,y,z]==1 and stage[x,y,z]==1:
                next_walk[x,y,z]= np.copy(walk[x2,y,z])#*(1/6))
            elif number == 4 and stage[x2,y,z]==0 and stage[x,y,z]==1:
                next_walk[i]=walk[i]#(1/6)**t

            elif number == 5 and stage[x,y2,z]==1 and stage[x,y,z]==1:
                next_walk[x,y,z]= np.copy(walk[x,y2,z])#*(1/6))
            elif number==5 and stage[x,y2,z]==0 and stage[x,y,z]==1:
                next_walk[i]=walk[i]#(1/6)**t

            elif number == 6 and stage[x,y,z2]==1 and stage[x,y,z]==1:
                next_walk[x,y,z]=np.copy(walk[x,y,z2])#*(1/6))
            elif number ==6 and stage[x,y,z2]==0 and stage[x,y,z]==1:
                next_walk[i]=walk[i]#(1/6)**t

            else: #stage[i]==0:
                continue
                #next_walk[x,y,z]=(1/6)**t

        walk = np.copy(next_walk)
    print(t,walk)
```

怪しい点、アドバイス等宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: どうやら、たとえばnumber=1で、x+1に移動するときに０であった場合、動かないという指示を加えているのにも関わらず、x+1の０を採用してしまっているみたいです。

Comment: メイン計算を書き直してみました。まだ少し上手くいかないです。

Comment: 自己解決しました！！！！！！！

Comment: おめでとうございます。量子ランダムウォークには興味がありますので、できればどの様に解決したのか回答していただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: 今回の質問は量子ランダムウォークではありません、ただの（古典）ランダムウォークです、よくいわれているランダムウォークです。元の質問のコードを書き直してしまってもよろしいのでしょうか？

Comment: 以前質問した、内容のことでしょうか、たしかに自力で再現できました。

Comment: すみません、勘違いをしていました。できれば、変更点などを回答として書いていただけると助かります(自分の回答をご自身で承認する事が可能です)。

Comment: 以前の質問(量子ランダムウォーク)については私の方では解く事ができなかったので、Rei さんがどうやって解いたのかについて知りたいのはやまやまなのですが、このサイトでやり取りするのは不適切なので、機会がありましたらその時にでも…と思います。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85274/discussion-between-rei-and-metropolis)しましょう。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決方法を以下に記します（万一間違っていた場合、教えて頂けると助かります）。

```
import random
import numpy as np
n = 27
itr = 10
step = [i for i in range(0,itr+1)]
r_list = [i for i in range(0,n)]
walk = np.zeros([n,n,n],dtype=np.uint8)
walk[0,0,0] = 1
prob =[]
time=[]
for t in step:
    if t == 0:
        pass
    else:
        number = random.randint(1,6)
        next_walk = np.zeros([n,n,n],dtype=np.uint8)
        for i in itertools.product(r_list,r_list,r_list):
            x = i[0]
            y = i[1]
            z = i[2]
        #Boundary condition
            x1 = (x-1 + n) % n
            x2 = (x+1) % n
            y1 = (y-1 + n) % n
            y2 = (y+1) % n
            z1 = (z-1 + n) % n
            z2 = (z+1) % n
            if  stage[i]== 0:
                continue
            else:
                if walk[i]==1:
                    if number == 1:
                        if stage[x2,y,z]==1:
                            next_walk[x2,y,z]=walk[i]
                        else:
                            next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[i]
                    elif number == 2:
                        if stage[x,y2,z]==1:
                            next_walk[x,y2,z]=walk[i]
                        else:
                            next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[i]
                    elif number == 3:
                        if stage[x,y,z2]==1:
                            next_walk[x,y,z2]=walk[i]
                        else:
                            next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[i]
                    elif number == 4:
                        if stage[x1,y,z]==1:
                            next_walk[x1,y,z]=walk[i]
                        else:
                            next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[i]
                    elif number == 5:
                        if stage[x,y1,z]==1:
                            next_walk[x,y1,z]=walk[i]
                        else:
                            next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[i]
                    elif number == 6:
                        if stage[x,y,z1]==1:
                            next_walk[x,y,z1]=walk[i]
                        else:
                            next_walk[x,y,z]=walk[i]
                else:
                    continue
```